# Use Window Authentication with AspNetCore Identity and login/password

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

I'm building an Intranet web application that should handle the following requirements:

- Allowing SSO using Windows Authentication and prepare a JWT token (with added claims privileges and other information) in order to access the rest of application resources
- Allowing to add domain users to custom roles in the application and grant custom privileges to roles (using AspNetRoleClaims table from Identity)
- Allowing to log in to application via the standard Login/Password form (e.g. in case of LDAP server issues). Domain accounts will be constantly synchronized to AspNetCore.Identity.AspNetUsers database table.

I have prepared a Windows Authentication functionality with this code in my `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddNegotiate();
```

After that I'm successfully I'm authorized using the endpoint:

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [HttpGet("token")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<string>>> GetToken()
    {
        var userName = User.Identity?.Name;

        if (userName is null)
            return Unauthorized();

        var exists = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

        var userGroups = GetUserADGroups(userName);
        
        // TODO: Firstly we should check here if user has proper AD role assigned to.
        // TODO: Then we should check user privileges against Identity DB and prepare the JWT Token and Claims and return it

        return userGroups;
    }

private static List<string> GetUserADGroups(string userName)
    {
        if (userName is null)
            return new List<string>();

        using var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        using var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName);
        
        if (user is null)
            return new List<string>();

        return user
            .GetGroups()
            .Select(x => x.SamAccountName)
            .ToList();
    }
```

But now in case if user is not authorized here I would like to redirect him to some login page and allow to put his login/password that will be verified against the Identity database. So I create an Identity setup:

```cs
        builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<GeoLinkDbContext>();
```

And to be honest I don't know what to do next in order to allow the user to put his login/password.

The next question is if the whole flow of using Windows Authentication with AspNetCore Identity as mentioned at the beginning is a good approach?

Comment: Do you want a reference like [AutoLoginMiddleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877084/asp-net-core-identity-with-windows-authentication)?

Comment: @Chen That's a good solution, but what about login/password functionality as an additional login setup beyond the Windows Authentication?

Comment: What does `additional login setup` mean? Would you like to be redirected to another login page if Windows authentication fails? It's difficult because windows authentication is not controllable. You can get the code into your custom login logic like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56167041/18789859).